# How to get all namespace/class/method headers in a c++ header file?

Tags: c++

How do you get all the public/visible (not necessary) 'structures' (don't know a proper name for them) in a c++ header file like their namespaces/classes/structs/methods, etc. in a nested manner, according to their order, like namespace -> class-> class method etc.

Comment: There's nothing like that, in C++. You must find some kind of a tool somewhere, that does this. It's unlikely that such a tool exists, since C++'s grammar is so complicated; and in any case asking for software recommendations is off-topic here.

Comment: Try looking a Doxygen.

Comment: For g++ or clang++, you can use `-E` to look at the preprocessed output.